# My samsung galaxy s4 won't turn on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, power-on

I left my phone charging over a 24 hour period and now it won't turn on. I tried cleaning it out, taking out the battery, and putting it on the charger. I don't have a spare battery to try. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I think your battery is dead, buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The battery is the best place to start. Overtime they tend to wear down. (I had the same issue on my Galaxy S 3 and it took a new battery)

Otherwise, it could be an issue with the motherboard or something more fragile in the phone. Could also be a power button failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of not starting up and flashing are related to the faulty power button. Here's the link you can follow on how to troubleshoot the power button if it's working properly or not using a voltmeter.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l_6fwzuIwA

Answer (score 0):

You could see if you get anything from removing the battery and connecting it via USB cable to a computer.  You'd be powering it from the USB cable, possibly enough to turn it on.